# Is it good practice to have Pages that inherit from a custom class which itself inherits from Page?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

The funny thing is that it worked. The compiler had no issues with the code, although it is something that I've never seen (maybe because I'm a novice). I would like to use the newly inherited base Page/class as a place to store commonly used code so that I don't have to duplicate anything. Take a look here:

```
public sealed partial class HumanPage : SpeciesBasePage;
public sealed partial class AnimalPage : SpeciesBasePage;
public class SpeciesBasePage : Page;
```

Obviously, it works because SpeciesBasePage implements the Page class. So you will also see that the related XAML page will have a different base class as its opening tag:

```
<local:SpeciesBasePage 
    x:Class="PageInheritanceProject.HumanPage" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    ...>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello, world!" />
    </Grid>
</local:SpeciesBasePage>
```

Is it okay to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Why is it funny that it works? That's exactly how inheritance in OOP is designed, isn't it? Please read about the FCoI (favor composition over inheritance) clean code principle, before you do that too often.

Comment: Good point. I'll correct it, although you can indirectly inherit. HumanPage indirectly inherits Page.

Comment: *"Is it okay to do this?"* - do you have some doubts? There are plenty of questions with "good/best practice" requirement (which is waaay too abstract to even consider asking question) in them and many of them are just "please look at my code and confirm it's correct" without any problem statement. To me it's [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) request, make sure to ask it [right](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

That's a fairly standard inheritance chain. In c# terms.
Two things to consider.

1)

Usage of Pages at all is the thing many commercial teams would question.

Many teams do not use pages at all and instead use usercontrols ( hosted in contentcontrols ).

2)

Inheriting from pages. You can't inherit xaml so why are you inheriting a UI control which is likely a container?

Comment: I guess you learn something new every day. I'll have to read more on that approach, also. Dealing with Pages can be annoying. Can you give me at least one good reason for using UserControls over Pages? Thanks.

Comment: Pages mean a frame, which comes with memory overhead complications in the form of the journal and caching state of controls.